# Vue.js 2 и vuetifyjs v-dialog

Tags: vue.js

Есть vue-компонент auth.vue c vuetify компонентом v-dialog:

```js
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
      
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'auth',
  props: {
    dialog: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Также есть vue-компонент App.vue c кнопкой и компонентом auth из auth.vue:

```js
<template>

    <v-app id="demo">   
        <v-btn @click="dialog = true">Show</v-btn>  
        <auth :dialog="dialog"></auth>
    </v-app>

</template>

<script>
    import auth from './components/auth.vue'
    
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        data() {
            return {
                dialog: false
            }
        },
        components: {
            auth
        }
   }
</script>
```

Мне нужно вывести диалог  из auth.vue по нажатию кнопки в app.vue.

Результат нажатия на кнопку:
Модальное окно появляется и работает,
но в консоль выводится сообщение:

*[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "dialog"*

Как правильно без ошибок показать диалог? Возможно я это делаю неправильно и есть другое решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос с помощью **ref**

```html
<!-- auth.vue -->

<template>
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
          
      </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name: 'auth',
      data () {
        return {  
          dialog: false
        }
      },
      methods: {
        showDialog: function () {
          this.dialog = true;
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<!-- app.vue -->
<template>

    <v-app id="demo">   
        <v-btn @click="showAuth()">Show</v-btn>  
        <auth ref="auth"></auth>
    </v-app>

</template>

<script>
    import auth from './components/auth.vue'
    
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {
            auth
        },
        methods: {
            showAuth: function () {
                this.$refs.auth.showDialog();
            }
        }
   }
</script>
```

Возможно есть другое решение, но на мой взгляд, это самое простое.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ по сути кроется в самом предупреждении. `Vue` ругается на то, что вы используете значение из `props` напрямую, вместо того, чтобы присвоить его в `data` или `computed` (тем самым создав для компонента локальное состояние). В связи с чем при ре-рендеринге родителя, потомок потеряет свое состояние. Также, вы меняете состояние и у родителя, что во `Vue` не рекомендуется делать напрямую. Просто создайте локальное состояние у дочернего компонента `auth.vue`.

```
data() {
    return {
        show: this.dialog
    }
},
```

И перебейте `v-model`

```
<v-dialog v-model="show">

</v-dialog>
```

И `Vue` от вас отстанет

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но тогда перестает работать кнопка. 
В Vue Tools:
show:false
dialog:true

Comment: @Alexandr в таком случае, советую вам почитать про `two way binding` https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Модификатор-sync

Comment: Мне не подходит связывание. Я хочу просто правильно вывести диалог <v-dialog> по нажатию кнопки.